# Is there a built-in matcher in rspec that matches methods & values of an instance to a dictionary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-rails

I'm new to ruby, rails and RSpec.   I'm writing a spec which verifies that an instance, `obj`, sent as an argument to a method satisfies the condition that, given a dictionary, `dict`, `obj.<key> == dict[key]` for all keys in the dictionary.   This is how I'm doing it in the spec:

```
Foo::BarService.should_receive(:the_message) do |obj|
  @dict.keys.each do |key|
    obj.__send__(key).should be(@dict[key])
    end
end
```

Is there a built-in rspec matcher for this?  Or a better, more ruby-ish or rspec/rails-ish way?

Comment: Is there just one test like this, or is this a general pattern where you plan on having a lot of tests that assert some receiver gets a message with an argument that "agrees" with a given dictionary?  If it's a one off test, it's better to be more explicit.  Do away with `@dict` and just put all the assertions you want to make: `ojb.key_1.should == value_1; obj.key_2.should == value_2`, etc.  If this type of test is going to come up a lot, write a custom matcher (Google it) with useful failure messages (e.g. it could tell you *all* the keys where the value is wrong, not just the first).

Comment: I already have @dict because it's sent as the params argument to `post :create`.    This is the only example I have right now, I'm not sure if it will come up again or not.    Your point is well taken about explict tests being a bit more clear.